# Cron not working in the new EC2 instance. If run manually then it's working

Tags: cron, amazon-ec2, aws

I have set up a new EC2 instance. Everything is working perfectly. Now this morning I have set the cron and below is an example of cron

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php https://www.xyz.in/api/cron/index.php
```

I have tested so many times but my cron is not working. If I hit manually cron url then it's working. I need to know if I have to set any settings in EC2 instance for running the cron.

Ubuntu version `22.04.3` LTS

Comment: See my answer  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673908/why-crontab-doesnt-execute-a-scheduled-bash-script/673918#673918

Comment: Referring to a script by its URL i.e. `https://www...` when passing it as an argument to a local interpreter i.e.  `/usr/bin/php` will not work as the interpreter will not read the code in that PHP script but rather the output (*HTML/TEXT/JS ...etc.*) by the web-server serving that script ... If you want to run the script on the server remotely, use e.g. `/bin/curl "https://www...." >/dev/null 2>1` instead.

Comment: @Raffa, Can you please help me with full example URL?

Comment: @Raffa, you mean i have to try */5 * * * *  https://www.xyz.in/api/cron/index.js file to run?

Comment: Sure ... `*/5 * * * * /bin/curl "https://www.xyz.in/api/cron/index.php" >/dev/null 2>1` ... That should run the target script on the target server by simply asking the web-server to serve that page like a web-browser would do ... Make sure the URL doesn't contain `%` characters as those will break the line in crontab unless escaped with `\`

Comment: @Raffa, Sorry , Can i know why you have added >/dev/null 2>1 ? do I need to add the same?

Comment: Yes `>/dev/null` will redirect the output `stdout` of the command to `/dev/null` thus discarding it and `2>1` will redirect the error(s) `stderr` to `stdout` and thus discarding it as well ... If you don't do that, you'll get alot of error logs in CRON but your command should run everytime nonetheless ... It's a good measure though.

Comment: @Raffa, Thank you so much for explanation.. Can you please check this link ? is it correct way to use?  */5 * * * * /bin/curl "https://www.xyz.in/api/cron/time.php" >/dev/null 2>1

Comment: Yes, but it's better to add the full working resolvable URL like to include the `www.` for example if that is needed to correctly resolve the URL and also specify the protocol prefix like `https://` i.e. better to visit that page in the web-browser first then copy and paste it from there to make sure it will work.

Comment: @Raffa, yes, I have tried that but stack overflow not allowing here to show that..  let me try above URL in cron

Comment: @Raffa, Yes, It's working. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: You are most welcome and I am happy I could help ... I've also added an answer so this post will be a reference to help others with the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to a PHP script by its URL i.e. `https://www...` when passing it as an argument to a local interpreter i.e. `/usr/bin/php` will not work as the interpreter will not read the code in that PHP script but rather the output (*HTML/TEXT/JS ...etc.*) by the web-server serving that script/page ... That is if that used interpreter/executable can handle sending and receiving HTTP/S requests which `/usr/bin/php` might not be able to handle after all and thus neither the web-server will respond nor the interpreter will read anything.

If you want to run the script on the server remotely, use e.g. `/bin/curl "https://www...." >/dev/null 2>1` instead.

... therefor, your crontab line should look something like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/curl "https://www.xyz.in/api/cron/index.php" >/dev/null 2>1
```

... that should run the target script/page on the target server by simply asking the web-server to serve that page like a web-browser would do ... Make sure the URL doesn't contain any `%` characters as those will break the line in crontab unless escaped with `\`.

`>/dev/null` will redirect the output `stdout` of the command to `/dev/null` thus discarding it and `2>1` will redirect the error(s) from `stderr` to `stdout` and thus discarding them as well ... If you don't do that, you'll get a lot of error logs from CRON, but your command should run every time nonetheless ... It's a good measure though or you can redirect (appending with `>>`) both to a custom log file instead of `/dev/null` if you wish or either like output with `>>/path/to/outlog` and error with `2>>/path/to/errlog`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. upvote from my side.

Comment: Just to add a little to the answer - If you have a local .php file on your server, that you want to run, then you can use `*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/myLocalScript.php` to run that file, like you would run it from the command line.